# iterating through a list error

Tags: python, pandas

```
I have a dataframe,delf
     Date        inp  name   
0  2017-08-07  2.3.6  ABC 
1  2017-08-07  2.3.6  ABC      
2  2017-08-08  2.3.6  TAC         
3  2017-08-22  2.5.9  TTT         
4  2017-09-23  0.8.0  TAC         
5  2017-10-09  2.3.6  ABC         
6  2017-10-09  2.3.6  TAC
7  2017-10-09  2.3.6  TAC                  
8  2017-10-23  0.8.0  TAC         
9  2017-11-08  6.2.6  ABC        

then another dataframe,trex
               2.3.6ABC  2.3.6TAC      2.5.9TTT      
August            2         1            0            
September         0         0            0             
October           1         2            0             
November          0         0            1             

another dataframe,dher
              2.3.6ABC  2.3.6TAC       
August            2         1                      
September         0         0                         
October           1         2                        
November          0         0
```

I want to get the distinct values in column: 'inp' of DELF which in this case is 4. Then, number of columns of TREX and DHER which is 3 and 2 in this case. How can I store the number of columns of the 2 dataframes,TREX  and DHER, then getting the percentage TREX  and DHER in df1. It should look like this:

```
                 noOfColumn      pct
  TREX                 3         3/4=75                      
  DHER                 2         2/4=50
```

I tried using this code:

```
df_list = [TREX,DHER]
idx, v = [], []
for i, df in enumerate(df_list, 1):
idx.append('{}'.format())
v.append(len(df.columns))
```

then,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(v, index=idx, columns=['noOfColumn'])
df['pct'] = df['noOfColumn'] / DELF.inp.nunique()
```

Not giving me the right output

Comment: `idx.append('{}'.format())` gives me an `IndexError` in 3.6. What is its purpose?

Comment: to append the name of the dataframe,trex and dher into the empty list,idx

Comment: `idx.append('{}'.format())` incorrect , `format` requires a variable. I think it should be `idx.append('{}'.format(i))`

Comment: @Stack even with `idx.append('{}'.format(i)) ` , the dataframe,df does not still represent the names in the `df_list ` as the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign name to your df

```
TREX.name='TREX'
DHER.name='DHER'
df_list = [TREX,DHER]
idx, v = [], []
for i, df in enumerate(df_list, 1):
    idx.append(df.name)
    v.append(len(df.columns))
df = pd.DataFrame(v, index=idx, columns=['noOfColumn'])
df['pct'] = df['noOfColumn'] / DELF.inp.nunique()
df
Out[55]: 
      noOfColumn   pct
TREX           3  0.75
DHER           2  0.50
```

Comment: its is still with the default index of pandas and not the dataframe,TREX and DHER